# Why aiomysql closing connection when conn.get_transaction_status() is True after I set isolation level twice?

Tags: python, mysql, innodb, isolation-level, aio-mysql

I found that connection will close after ***I set isolation level twice***.

I accidentally set this twice and found a unexpected behavior. ( at least, I do not expect that.

After I set some log, I found the reason is that this line https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql/blob/master/aiomysql/pool.py#L223 return `True`.

example code is here https://gist.github.com/Bear1110/1115bef832836d31079d0ceb194e56da.

OUTPUT is below

```
1 1
False
[{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}]
1 1
------------------------------
1 1
True
[{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}]
0 0
```

The last line `0 0` is meaning pool close the connection after released connection.  `print(pool.freesize, pool.size)`

I found that flag which is `conn.get_transaction_status()` meaning is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/mysql-server/latest/mysql__com_8h.html#a1d854e841086925be1883e4d7b4e8cad).

But, actually I do not know why this flag become `True` after I set isolation level twice ?

I just wonder why need close connection when this flag is `True` ?

Could any one help me understand this logic ?  Thanks

I post discussion [here](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiomysql/discussions/926), too.
Pypi package is [here](https://pypi.org/project/aiomysql/).